# Website/Database text encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, encoding

We imported a website from another server to our server. The code and database is 100% the same. 
But the text on the website seems to have a wrong encoding.

Example:
In the database the word "Australië" is "AustraliĂŤ" while on the website its shown as Australi??.
I can fix the ?? with adding mysql_set_charset("utf8",$this->db); after the database connection.
But then its shown like in the database like "AustraliĂŤ" wich is incorrect. I tried different encodings in apache, after database and in meta tags.

The easiest way would be to change the data in the database but there is to much data in it to do this.

Anyone has a solution for this problem? Have been searching and trying a lot off things for hours.

Comment: what is the column data type?

Comment: Do you mean that the old database is corrupted?

Comment: the table are utf8_unicode_ci. It is on all the tables that have text. The old database is not corrupt but i think the data in it is not utf8 while the table type is utf8. I think it would be logical if for example Australië is saved as Australië in database and not as AustraliĂŤ.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to:

- set the MySQL connection collation to uft8_general_ci in the database
- run `SET NAMES 'utf8'` and `SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_unicode_ci` in your PHP files
- make sure all your PHP files are saved with UTF-8 encoding and do not feature a BOM
- make sure the cells in your table are `utf8_general_ci`
- make sure that MySQL charset is UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

This is what I have. With this setup I see all characters in the database (phpMyAdmin) as they really appear on the website itself.

I have encountered a similar issue when I had a mismatch of encodings, i.e. I was saving data to a UTF-8 database by a ISO-8859-1 encoded site...

Hope this helps you.